# Learn language learning techniques in school before starting to learn foreign languages?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request

In countries where the main language is not a world language, students often learn foreign languages in school. However, students are not taught about how to learn a language effectively.

Has any research been done on how effective it is to have a language learning *techniques* course in school before starting to learn these second languages? Do students who have had a course in language learning techniques perform much better than students who don't?

Such language learning techniques course should include learning about several techniques (e.g. flash cards) that have been shown to be effective by research.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I am a little unclear of what you are asking.

Comment: @callyalater I clarified it by adding another formulation of the question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. For most people "Starting to learn" means starting to learn **at school**, at least for the first foreign language (two foreign languages are compulsory at secondary school level in quite  a lot of places) so we can expect that the majority  of people who learn a second language learn it at school ([here](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-press-releases/-/3-01022016-AP) you'll find figures about secondary schools in Europe). Learning a second language can start in primary school.  So what does "starting to learn these second languages" mean for you?

Comment: To answer what I understand  of your question: in some countries learning techniques (i.e. how the student should set about learning whatever subject the are studying) are part of the curricular, not only for languages, for everything that is learnt at school. Not specific to languages, should the question be asked on [academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Laure No, because there can also be courses specific to language learning. Also, Academica is just for graduate and above, while this question is probably high school and undergraduate.

Comment: @wythagoras, I do not belong to the Academia community, so I trust what you say. But what I will be adamant on the importance of learning techniques being taught from the very start of the learning process, i.e. primary school. It is much too late to be fully effective if only started in secondary school.

Comment: @Laure I agree, which is why I stated *before starting to learn second languages*. It may be because of different education systems; language learning only start in secondary school in my home country (though there are proposals to change that). There is a little English in primary school, but it is redone at secondary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38061/discussion-between-laure-and-wythagoras).

Comment: Interesting question. I can only guess, so a comment, not an answer: I think the knowledge of such techniques will stick better if they are applied from the start. OTOH, one could do that in a language techniques course, too, before "officially" learning the first language. I wish we'd had that at school.

Comment: There is definitely a lot of research on language learning strategies used at secondary-school level (e.g. of the type "what strategies do students actually use"). It's harder to find anything about courses that are taught *before* the start of actual language classes. If you don't know yet what the challenges are of learning a foreign language, interest may be limited because the strategies appear too abstract.

Answer (score 9):

Some techniques are certainly more effective than others, as you noted.

I think it's definitely effective to learn how to improve your learning process, as long as the amount of time spent learning the techniques is less than the time you saved. Since acquiring a second language often takes years, the benefits seem clear to me. Also, since "use flash cards" is not hard to get across, there's at least an 80-20 tradeoff that can be achieved.

In school, though, I think the game changes. The way language is taught in school is already not always the most effective. Case in point is the American way where we don't start teaching a language until middle school or high school.

In school, the benefit would come if the education system was adjusted and if *teachers* were taught the best way for their students to learn languages. It is the teachers' responsibilities to apply the most effective techniques in the classroom. Great coaches are highly sought after because they teach their athletes in the most effective ways.

I don't know of any research on the increased language abilities of those students. I would, however, think they would be directly related to the relative effectiveness of different techniques.

Comment: While *"use flash cards" is not hard to get across*, research has shown that many students use them ineffectively.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are important differences between the pronunciation of American and European vowels that I covered in my answer to [this question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/248/).
Learning these differences (even between American and British English) will help you study European languages.

It would also help if a student learned to trace the "foreign" etymologies of common English words, especially those of his target language.

I haven't seen any studies on my proposals, but their advantages should be self-evident.